# Better way to have JavaScript function wait until transition is finished than just setting `setTimeout()` to same as transition-duration?

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, settimeout

I'm using JavaScript to style a `<span>` tag (that is already styled in CSS to be cyan) to turn green when it is clicked, and then right back to cyan.  In the CSS, its `transition-duration` property is set to `100ms`.  I don't want Javascript to set the `color` back to cyan before it's finished changing to green, so naturally, I use a `setTimeout()` to delay it the amount of time that the transition will take (`100ms`), as you can see in the code below, and I improved it a little after looking at other questions regarding this, but they still didn't seem to be the most efficient.

## Code:

```js
// Script is here and not in src in order to make it easier for you to copy and test run.
document.getElementById("text").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("text").style.color = "Green";
    setTimeout(function() {document.getElementById("text").style.color = "Cyan";}, 100); // Timeout time same as transition-duration.
});
```

```css
#info-display{
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
    font: small-caps bold 5vw 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
#text {
    color: Cyan;
    background-color: Black;
    padding: 0.1vw 1vw 0.1vw;
    border-radius: 25% 25% 15% 15%;
    transition-duration: 100ms;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="info-display"><span id="text">~ Words to Click. ~</span></h1>
```

I need to know if there is a better way than this; some way that JavaScript can detect when a CSS `transition` has finished, so that the tedious work of changing the `transition` time in two places does not have to happen.

If anybody can help me find a way, it would be fantastic! 

Thanks!


P.S. Please don't bother asking, "Why an `<h1>` tag?" or anything like that, it's just what I'm using in the full program that this is for.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is. Take a look at the following `EventListener`:

```js
elem.addEventListener('transitionend', function(){
    //Do something
});
```

Comment:  Thank you, I just found out about this before returning here and seeing this. 

Comment: I don't understand it actually, what is the `(event) =>` supposed to represent?

Comment: @RobertBradley You don't need that there, I edited my answer to make it (hopefully) more simple. You can also take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/transitionend_event for more info.

Comment: And `elem` is just the element upon which you applied the transition

Comment: Yeah, okay, I was just testing it because I was unsure if it would work for functions too, since you didn't put that at first. Thank you for all your help.